# Which MySQL Select query is correct

Tags: mysql, select, having

Note that I have similar topics with different questions,

I'm learning `MySQL`. I came across some multiple-choice questions.
If I doubted what the answer was or was not convinced it's correct I started searching google, stackoverflow and the mysql site.
However for some I still couldn't confirm what the correct answer was.

Therefore I ask the question here.

Question:
Table `Employees` is created. You want to retrieve the information of those employees who have at least one person reporting to them. Which of the following queries will you execute to accomplish the task?

- A. `SELECT employee_id, last_name, job_id, department_id FROM Employees WHERE employee_id EXISTS(SELECT manager_id WHERE manager_id is NULL);`
- B. `SELECT employee_id, last_name, job_id, department_id FROM Employees HAVING employee_id IN(SELECT manager_id FROM Employees WHERE manager_id is NOT NULL);`
- C. `SELECT employee_id, last_name, job_id, department_id FROM Employees outer WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 'x' FROM Employees WHERE manager_id = outer.employee_id);`
- D. `SELECT employee_id, last_name, job_id, department_id FROM Employees HAVING employee_id WHERE employee_id IN (SELECT manager_id WHERE manager_id is NOT NULL);`

  - A and D don't have a `FROM` clause in the `subquery`. I guess this is invalid (or just a typo in the question?)
  - The proposed answer is C. However I believe that this can't work because the reserved keyword "outer" is used as an alias here. Please correct me if I'm wrong.
  - So actually only B is left here.
  - Answer D order is incorrect. (`WHERE` should be before `HAVING`)
  - Answer A is invalid because the `subquery` queries for `IS NULL`.

If you have any remark about this question/answer or for any of my remarks I'm happy to hear it!

Comment: at C, `outer.employee_id` is equal to `Employees.employee_id` btw. Although, is that not for a homework or tests ? :P ( B )

Comment: I'm preparing for certification and found a few example questions on the internet. Note that OUTER is a reserved keyword. So I would think this just can't work. Or am I wrong?

Comment: When I try C on a test table I get: SELECT id from emp outer WHERE exists (SELECT 'x' FROM emp WHERE mid = outer.id);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'outer WHERE exists (SELECT 'x' FROM emp WHERE mid = outer.id)' at line 1

Comment: As a note for anyone else trying this question: if a reserved word is used for an alias it has to be in between single quotes or backticks.

Comment: Can we vote for 'none of the above'? (And don't use reserved words as column/table aliases)

Answer (score 0):

According to given information B seems correct with a correction that there should be where and not any having in statement but can better tell you if you upload DB schema

Comment: Strange. I recreated this example with a table that has 2 colums: id and mid(note that there is no db schema supplied). Then put a few entries in. Left some mid columns null if they didn't had a manager. Query: select id, mid from emp having id in(select mid from emp where mid is not null); It only give me the entry that had people reporting to them. Note that this question is about mysql. Maybe other db servers have different behavior on the having clause.